# Using ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 as authoritative country list?

Tags: list, iso, country, country-codes, countries

Is this an authoritative list of countries I can use for my application?

http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/english_country_names_and_code_elements.htm

> English country names and code
>   elements
>
> This list states the country names
>   (official short names in English) in
>   alphabetical order as given in ISO
>   3166-1 and the corresponding ISO
>   3166-1-alpha-2 code elements.
>
> This list is updated whenever a change
>   to the official code list in ISO
>   3166-1 is effected by the ISO 3166/MA.
>
> It lists 248 official short names and
>   code elements.

Not exactly programming related, but would be helpful to others seeking to build such a list in their programs!

Answer (score 2):

As you said, it is not exactly a 100% programming question, so I will proceed carefully. As you may see from the United Nations Statistics Division web site, they are [citing ISO 3166](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/methods/m49/m49.htm) as authoritative, but remember they purpose is towards statistics. Besides ISO is a NGO without other members than the national member bodies of each country, headquarters personnel and several committes/joints. To see what's "authorized" actually you may be better seeing what's considered [not recognized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrecognized_countries#Non-UN_member_states_not_recognised_by_any_state).

I would take the [UN.M49 list](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/methods/m49/m49alpha.htm) as authoritative, but if your application gets really serious about geopolitical stuff, check for not obvious cases, for example the Holy See which holds observer status in the United Nations.